# href link not woking. Is ajax or java stopping this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to link pages within this builder depending on selections. I have made separate html files for the selections e.g. product-01-01.html, product-01-02.html etc.

The problem I am having now is to link the pages when selection is made. I have used an href, however when the selection is made and the button (in this example accessories) at the bottom right it doesn't take you to the file selected.

Here is the template I am using... [Product builder](https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-builder/index.html)

Here is my first html file that links to the second page fine:

```js
if (!window.jQuery) document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"><\/script>');
```

```html
<div class="cd-product-builder">
  <header class="main-header">
    <h1>Product Builder</h1>

    <nav class="cd-builder-main-nav disabled">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#models">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#colors">Colors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#accessories">Accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <a href="https://codyhouse.co/?p=16220" class="cd-nugget-info hide-on-mobile">Article &amp; Download</a>
  </header>

  <div class="cd-builder-steps">
    <ul>
      <li data-selection="models" class="active builder-step">
        <section class="cd-step-content">
          <header>
            <h1>Select Model</h1>
            <span class="steps-indicator">Step <b>1</b> of 4</span>
          </header>

          <a href="https://codyhouse.co/?p=16220" class="cd-nugget-info hide-on-desktop">Article &amp; Download</a>

          <ul class="models-list options-list cd-col-2">
            <li class="js-option js-radio" data-price="42400" data-model="product-01">
              <span class="name">BMW i3</span>
              <img src="img/product01_col01.jpg" alt="BMW i3">
              <span class="price">from $42.400</span>
              <div class="radio"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="js-option js-radio" data-price="140700" data-model="product-02">
              <span class="name">BMW i8</span>
              <img src="img/product02_col01.jpg" alt="BMW i8">
              <span class="price">from $140.700</span>
              <div class="radio"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </li>
      <!-- additional content will be inserted using ajax -->
    </ul>
  </div>

  <footer class="cd-builder-footer disabled step-1">
    <div class="selected-product">
      <img src="img/product01_col01.jpg" alt="Product preview">

      <div class="tot-price">
        <span>Total</span>
        <span class="total">$<b>0</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="cd-builder-secondary-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="next nav-item">
          <ul>
            <li class="visible"><a href="#0">Colors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Summary</a></li>
            <li class="buy"><a href="#0">Buy Now</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="prev nav-item">
          <ul>
            <li class="visible"><a href="#0">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Colors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Accessories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <span class="alert">Please, select a model first!</span>
  </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the page html that comes up when you select the first model:

```html
<li data-selection="colors" class="builder-step first-load">
  <section class="cd-step-content">
    <header>
      <h1>Select Color</h1>
      <span class="steps-indicator">Step <b>2</b> of 4</span>
    </header>

    <ul class="cd-product-previews">
      <li class="selected"><img src="img/product01_col01.jpg" alt="Product Preview" class="product-preview"></li>
      <li><img src="img/product01_col02.jpg" alt="Product Preview" class="product-preview"></li>
      <li><img src="img/product01_col03.jpg" alt="Product Preview" class="product-preview"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="cd-product-customizer">
      <li data-content="White - $0" data-price="0" class="selected"><a data-color="white" data-model="product-01-01" href="product-01-01.html">White - $0</a></li>
      <li data-content="Mineral Grey - $550" data-price="550"><a data-color="grey" data-model="product-01-02" href="product-01-02.html">Mineral Grey - $550</a></li>
      <li data-content="Orange Metallic - $550" data-price="550"><a data-color="orange" data-model="product-01-03" href="product-01-03.html">Orange Metallic - $550</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</li>
```

This is where the problem starts. If you select the white option it should take you to this html file saved as product-01-01.html, but it just comes up as a blank screen.

If it was just HTML and CSS im sure it would be working so I have tried playing around with the location of the href but I am starting to think its something to do with the ajax or javascript.

Comment: Code snippets surround the code with `<HTML>` and `<BODY>` already and every source (css or js) can't be loaded anyway

Comment: The full code is surrounded with <HTML> and <body></body> tags if that is what you mean?

Comment: That was just my edit comment

Comment: Oh sorry i see. thank you.